# 'Drag down' formula over 20,000+ rows without manually having to drag down and wait

Tags: google-sheets

Ive got a google docs spreadsheet with c. 20,000 rows ive got a formal i want to run for each row, at the moment im inputting the formula into `D1` and then pulling the formula down, although this works i have to wait with my hand on the mouse for about 5 mins to reach the bottom of the spreadsheet.

Is there a quicker / better way to do this ?

**UPDATE** Ive made an example google drive spreadsheet here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GyPEcTclo-7HGrGkpp86WyguKF6VJblCzBE9qXm-7mU/edit#gid=647850816

Ive got the numbers 1-500 in cells A1-A500 in B for each row ive written a formula to check if a the number is odd or even. For this example (500 rows) its not a problem to drag the formula down, but this is just an example data set.

Comment: In general an arrayFormula() would help. However with the present amount of info in your post it is impossible to say if that will work.

Comment: @JPV please see updated question with link to google drive

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve with that formula but =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A1:A), odd(A1:A)=A1:A,)) should turn that formula into an arrayformula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either of these:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A),IF(ODD(A1:A)=A1:A, TRUE,FALSE),))

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ODD(A1:A)=A1:A, TRUE,FALSE)
```